# Trying to export an array to csv using powershell (array objects are ; delimited and contain newlines)

Tags: powershell, scripting

Okay, so I have this array, which is essentially an `Import-Csv` of a CSV file.  Each object in the array is an entire CSV row.  The input file renders properly when I open it with Excel (The columns are correct)

This CSV file is comma delimited, in the following example format:

> "first","second","this is all
>
> the third
>
> column","fourth"

I have gotten everything in my script to work properly, except for the part where I need to write this array to a .csv file in a format which will properly render.  I have been having issues using `Out-File`, `Export-Csv`, and I even tried [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/09/23/use-powershell-to-work-with-csv-formatted-text.aspx) but it doesn't give me exactly what I need.  Each object needs to be a new line in the csv file, appear only once, and must adhere to Excel's rendering of CSV files (i.e. each column needs to be double quoted and comma delimited).

I even got so desperate that I'm trying to manually format this thing correctly by doing this:

```
$Array | % { $_ -replace "`"@`{","`n`"" } | % { $_ -replace "}`"","`"`n" } | % { $_ -replace "`;","`"`;`"" } | % { $_ -replace "Plugin ID=","" } | % { $_ -replace "CVE=","" } | % { $_ -replace "CVSS=","" } | % { $_ -replace "Risk=","" } | % { $_ -replace "Host=","" } | % { $_ -replace "Protocol=","" } | % { $_ -replace "Port=","" } | % { $_ -replace "Name=","" } | % { $_ -replace "Synopsis=","" } | % { $_ -replace "Solution=","" } | % { $_ -replace "Description=","" } | % { $_ -replace "Plugin Output=","" } | % { $_ -replace "`";`"","`",`"" } | Out-File "$dirResults\$Results-$Time.csv"
```

Essentially, what I'm doing here is a couple of things:

- Remove @{ from the beginning and } from the end of each object
- Change the delimeter from ; to ,
- Put each column in double quotations
- Remove the ColumnHeader= from the beginning of each value

Here is a snippet of code:

```
$arrayHeader = @("Plugin ID;CVE;CVSS;Risk;Host;Protocol;Port;Name;Synopsis;Description;Solution;Plugin Output")
$OutterArrayException = Import-Csv "$dirExceptions\$FileException" -Delimiter ","
$InnerArrayScanMe = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
# This method keeps the arrays separate types
FOREACH ( $Object in $OutterArrayScanMe )
        {   $InnerArrayScanMe.Add("$Object") | Out-Null }
# Note that the OutterArrayException is an Import-Csv from a similarly formatted file as OutterArrayScanMe
FOREACH ( $Exception in $OutterArrayException )
        { $InnerArrayScanMe.Remove("$Exception") }
# This method keeps the arrays separate types
$OutterArrayScanMe = @($arrayHeader) + @($InnerArrayScanMe)
$OutterArrayScanMe | Export-Csv "$dirResults\$FileScanMe-$startTime.csv" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

**UPDATE**:
When I use export-csv, the new lines for an object place the information as a new row in the csv.  Thus, something that should look like this gets really messy.

**UPDATE2**:
There have been some questions about what the format looks like and what the issues are with the format.  To clear those up, I have included a single object in the array which demonstrates the issue.  Remember, what happens in my script is there is an import-csv of a properly formatted CSV (Has multi line, etc. and renders perfectly), removal of unnecessary objects (using $array.Remove), and then a dump to file (Out-File or Export-Csv).  So simple, yet so broken...

**Example Array Object** (Out-File):
@{Plugin ID=#####; CVE=CVE-####-####; CVSS=#.#; Risk=Medium; Host=###.###.###.###; Protocol=xxx; Port=##; Name=Microsoft ASP.NET xxx; Synopsis=A framework used by the remote web server
vulnerability.; Description=The web server running on the remote host appears to be using Microsoft
ASP.NET, and may be affected by a vulnerability.

Additionally, there is speculation that this vulnerability could result
in unicorns and rainbows if an attacker with physical access to the machine
plugs in.; Solution=Use an magic filter to block requests to naughty sites.; Plugin Output=
Nessus received an naughty page or related error message by requesting
the following URL :

hxxp://###.###.###.###/xxx/xxxxxxxxx
}

**Example Array Object** (Export-Csv):
#TYPE System.String
"Length"
"616"

Comment: What was wrong with the way it renedered when you used export-csv?

Comment: When you save as CSV in Excel 2013, it's delimited with ";" not "," and text is not always in quotes (actually never when I try).  What is the sample above ? Is it "input.csv" ? then you modify it, export it and want to keep the same format(multiline per object), or do you want to remove the newlines? Please provide sample for output csv.

Comment: "first","second","this is all

    the third

    column","fourth"
 Are all new lines?

Comment: Please give an example of what you want to export to a CSV file.

Comment: @Graimer I'm referring to in quotes when I have multi-line fields.  When I don't have multi-line fields, they are not quoted.

Comment: @AthomSfere No, they should all show up as a single row.  See the link in the update for more clarity.

Comment: @JPBlanc The information I'm manipulating is a Nessus CSV export.  Here is an example:  http://static.tenable.com/oldsite/blog/img/6a00d8345495f669e20168eb8b3cc4970c

Comment: It's still unclear for me. I've submitted an "answer". Please tell me if that's your situation :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the script, at this step:

```
$InnerArrayScanMe = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList  
# This method keeps the arrays separate types  
FOREACH ( $Object in $OutterArrayScanMe )  
        {   $InnerArrayScanMe.Add("$Object") | Out-Null }
```

The $InnerArrayScanMe successfully adds the objects from the normal array $OutterArrayScanMe, without changing the array types, however because it is being put into a .NET array, the data is formatted incorrectly from here on out.

The point of doing it the initial way was so I could use the .NET array's .Add and .Remove methods.  The workaround so that we don't need to reference objects to be removed by index looks something like this:

```
FOREACH ( $Exception in $ArrayException )
{
    $ArrayScanMe = $ArrayScanMe | Where-Object {"$_" -ne "$Exception"};
}
```

That then allows us to do a basic Export-Csv

```
$ArrayScanMe | Export-Csv "$dirResults\$FileScanMe-$startTime.csv" -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be with how your manipulating the array. Check this out:

Test.csv

```
"Age";"Name"
12;"Test name"
13;"My Other
test"
```

Script

```
$Array = Import-Csv .\test.csv -Delimiter ";"

#$Array.Remove() is NOT a valid method. An array is of fixed size, and you will get an exception
#Instead, create a new array of items that are filtered through your rules.
#My test rule is only kids who are not 12 years old
$Newarray = $Array | Where-Object { $_.Age -ne "12" }

$Newarray | Export-Csv .\out.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

Out.csv

```
"Age";"Name"
"13";"My Other
test"
```

Everything is like it should be.

DO NOT use `-replace` on objects. It will convert the object to a string, and you will get the outputs you provided in update2. Ex:

```
$Array = Import-Csv .\test.csv -Delimiter ";"

$Array -replace "`r`n" | Export-Csv .\out2.csv -Delimiter ";"
$Array -replace "`r`n" | Out-File out2.txt
```

Out2.csv

```
#TYPE System.String
"Length"
"25"
"28"
```

The "TYPE" part is just because you didn't specify `-NoTypeInformation` with `Export-CSV`

Out2.txt

```
@{Age=12; Name=Test name}
@{Age=13; Name=My Othertest}
```

Btw, `Out-File` is not a way to export objects, but still, after `-replace` your array of objects became an array of strings, like the output in Out2.txt

**EDIT** `$OutterArrayScanMe = @($arrayHeader) + @($InnerArrayScanMe)` This is your problem. You merge two arrays together. The first object in your new array will be a string-object. `Export-CSV` uses the first object's properties as headers for every object. Since the first object is a string(only Length property), all objects will be exported with `Length` property only.

As said, `Export-CSV` uses the objects properties as headers(unless you specify another header-definition like `| Select Age, Name | Export-Csv`). So if `$InnerArrayScanMe` is an array of objects with the same properties, simply use:

```
$InnerArrayScanMe | Export-Csv "$dirResults\$FileScanMe-$startTime.csv" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

and `Export-CSV` will figure out the headings by itself. Summary: DON'T add that header-string of yours to the array. If you need a specific order orneed to exclude some properties, you can use pass an string-array to `select-object` define the header, like this:

```
$arrayHeader = @("Plugin ID","CVE","CVSS","Risk","Host","Protocol","Port","Name","Synopsis","Description","Solution","Plugin Output")

$arrlist | Select-Object -Property $arrayHeader | 
Export-Csv "$dirResults\$FileScanMe-$startTime.csv" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: When using Excel it seems to have no problem showing multi-line fields as long as they are properly formatted.  I do not want to remove the newlines, I just want to make sure that when a newline is in the CSV it is formatted in a way that Excel will recognize it should be a single entry.

Comment: Either I'm having a "stupid-day" or you're not explaining it well enough. If you open the first sample in my "answer" (with `;` instead of `,`) which is the "proper way" to provide multiline-values in csv, it WILL be read correct in excel. However, you have to resize the rows height to see all the text. Is that what you want? For Excel to understand that it needs to stretch?

Comment: Via update3, my output is: 
"Length"
"91"
"91"
"616"
"1234"
"1234"
"616"
"616"
"616"
"1233"
"1234"
"607"
"616"
"616"
"852"
"852"

Comment: I did some more testing the issue is the different types of arrays.  (aka "$InnerArrayScanMe = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList")  As soon as the objects get added to that array, they turn into garbage (reformatted, adds @{}, etc.) and don't work well with Export-Csv.

Comment: The issue is what I described in the edit to my answer. I'm 99.9% sure. It's not the fact that you combine two arrays, it's that the objects in the array are not the same. `$arrayHeader` is the first item in the new array you create when you combine them, it's object is a string, and `Export-CSV` uses that as a template for how the other objects are(which is wrong). Did you try the last sample? The one using `Select-Object` to specify the header.?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand your problem, you can do the following :

```
Import-Csv C:\temp\nessus.csv | where {$_.risk -eq "high"}
Import-Csv C:\temp\nessus.csv | where {$_.risk -eq "high"} | select host -Unique
```

You can export it to a CSV editable with Excel

```
Import-Csv C:\temp\nessus.csv | where {"high","medium","low" -contains $_.risk} | select "Plugin ID", CVE, CVSS, Risk, Host, Protocol, Port, Name | Export-Csv 'c:\temp\nessusExcel.csv' -Delimiter ';'
```

You can show in a gridview :

```
Import-Csv C:\temp\nessus.csv | where {"high","medium","low" -contains $_.risk} | select "Plugin ID", CVE, CVSS, Risk, Host, Protocol, Port, Name | Out-GridView
```

Export to an HTM file :

```
Import-Csv C:\temp\nessus.csv | where {"high","medium","low" -contains $_.risk} | select "Plugin ID", CVE, CVSS, Risk, Host, Protocol, Port, Name | ConvertTo-Html -As List > report.html
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear; the script imports a csv, then does work on it, comparing it to other files, parsing entries, etc.  At that point I have a "final array" which I would like output to a file in a good format.  My issue is that during that output stage, the format is messy because it seems to want to add @{} around each object in the array, and it does not quote properly for multi-line entries to be parsed properly.  The input is in this proper format, and the format is not manually changed while in an array.  It seems that powershell is changing the format slightly (See bullets).

Comment: Can you give an example of `$Array` for example in an xml file with `Export-Clixml` ?

Comment: Please see my update2 and let me know if this gives you what you were looking for.  I did an Export-Clixml and provided an obfuscated single line (There are multiple entries that are formatted exactly the same).  I obviously removed the <S></S>.